# Opening apps in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: windows

I recently move on ubuntu from windows. I am facing too much problems. Please give some web links so that I can easily learn ubuntu.

Comment: Assuming that you are able to use google (and that you _did_ use it) - you really (really!) need to be more precise about what you are looking for here. A good start would be if you describe the "too many problems" in a more elaborate way. Preferably one question per problem.

Comment: I agree that the question is not well phrased: I understood it as a question of where to get general help for using Ubuntu.  Also the title does not really match the question. (But remember that this place is supposed to be newby friendly)

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the Ubuntu icon at the top left of the screen something called the Dash will open. It will have a search panel. Type the word help and you will see an icon of a blue circle with a white question mark ( ? ). Click on it to open the Ubuntu Desktop guide for 11.10 or drag the icon to the panel on the left (called the Launcher) and the icon will stick in the Launcher so that you can access the Ubuntu Desktop Guide easily whenever you need to. The guide will explain how to remove icons from the Launcher.

This link will bring you to an on-line version of the Ubuntu Desktop Guide

[On-line Ubuntu Desktop Guide - 11.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/index.html)

Another source of Ubuntu information is the [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community) . Please remember, that just as Ubuntu is under progressive development so also is the documentation. Not only that but many of us are still using earlier versions of Ubuntu. So, what might seem out of date to someone using the latest Ubuntu is not out of date for those using earlier versions.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be the [ubuntu manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org/).

Unfortunately the manual is not yet ready for Ubuntu 11.10. You can read the version currently being edited [here](http://ubuntu-manual.org/proofread/gswu1110/en).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of ubuntu! You may want to check out the Ubuntu Desktop Guide, located at https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/index.html. Hope you like ubuntu!